# HTML1506: Unexpected token <script>

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

I have an error that only appears in Internet Explorer and Edge where I am getting `HTML1506: Unexpected token in line 213,1`. My suspicion is that it has to do with the way my webcomponents/polyfills are loading, but at this point it's a pretty complicated web of components and scripts, so narrowing down the source is a pain!

Here is the code segment containing line 213:

```
210 </body>
211 </html>
212
213 <script>
214 /********************************
215 /TEMPLATE VARS
216 /*******************************/
217 var save_url = '';  
218 var base_url = 'http://disalle.dev.activemls.com/';
```

live site:
http://disalle.dev.activemls.com

Comment: Why is the script tag after the closing html element?

Comment: its not i just wanted to show the code before and after line 213 in case it may be relevant

Comment: On your live page the script tag is after closing body tag, which is invalid HTML. Just move it to body.

Comment: actually even with fixing the script inside the html tags, I still seem to be having this problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like you have you scripts after your closing HTML document.

Try:

```
</body>
<script>
/********************************
/TEMPLATE VARS
/*******************************/
var save_url = '';  
var base_url = 'http://disalle.dev.activemls.com/';
// More Stuff Here
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I am literally punching my own face on this one.

Comment: I still got the error in IE and Edge until I also moved the `script` _inside_ the `body` tag as well as the `html` tag.

Comment: I'm still getting this error: 

HTNML1506: Unexpected token
localhost:3700 (16,1)


15    </body>
16    <script src="./assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error in Internet Explorer, place the script at the end of the `<body>` tag:

```html
 <body>
    
    // more
   
    <script>
    /********************************
    /TEMPLATE VARS
    /*******************************/
    var save_url = '';  
    var base_url = 'http://disalle.dev.activemls.com/';

    // more

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```